# Почему данный скрипт не записывает в массив число 9

Tags: php

Код:

```
$arr = array();

    for ($i = 2; $i <= 20; $i++) { 
        $flag = true;
          for ($j = 2; $j < $i; $j++) {
            if( $i % $j == 0)
                $flag = false;
      }
        if($flag==true)
            $arr[] = $i; 
    }  
    var_dump($arr);
```

Почему в результате выполнения в массив не запишется число **9** ? Ведь есть условие **if( $i % $j == 0)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Элементарно**, Ватсон

9 % 3 == 0

Вы ищите простые числа, а 9 не является простым числом, т.к. кратно 3.

Answer (score 0):

> Ведь есть условие if( $i % $j == 0)

Которое то выполняется, то нет.

Попробуйте воспользоваться отладчиком для инспекции переменных на каждой итерации цикла. Или, если по каким-то экзотическим причинам отладчика в хозяйстве нет, просто выводить на консоль значения `$i`, `$j` и выражения `$i % $j`, увидите всё своими глазами.

Comment: а в какой части кода  "просто выводить на консоль значения $i, $j и выражения $i % $j"   ?

Comment: @Sven, для начала стоит научиться пользоваться отладчиком. Ни за что не поверю, что ваши условия настолько экзотические, что его нет. А вот потом уже и придёт понимание, где какой отладочный вывод расставлять и  в каких случаях.